# Add if not nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I write a one-liner for the following?

```
x = y + (z if != nil)
```

I tried a few different things and also searched, but can't seem to find anything that's specific to this.

I tried:

```
x = y + z? z : 0
```

but that didn't work (syntax?) and even if it did, it feels sloppy.

Comment: x = y + (z ? z : 0)  would be the syntax you were shooting for.  Whether or not this is more clear than the z.to_i is up to you... I'm not sure I'm comfortable with converting nil.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
x = y + z.to_i
```

`nil.to_i` will return 0, so you'll be adding nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Your second attempt was trying to nil-check `z` with the ternary operator. This might be a more visible nil-check:

```
x = y + (z || 0)
```

Just for fun, say you wanted to nil-check all of your values before adding:

```
[1,2,nil,4,7,nil,23].map(&:to_i).inject(&:+) # => 37
```

#### Update

Or as improved by @hirolau: (cleaner and faster)

```
[1,2,nil,4,7,nil,23].compact.inject(&:+) # => 37
```

Without the `inject`, here's my benchmark comparison (for n=1,000,000):

```
          user       system     total      real
compact:  0.520000   0.000000   0.520000   (0.516290)
to_i:     1.380000   0.000000   1.380000   (1.372772)
```

Comment: `array.compact.inject(:+)` looks better.

Comment: I think I prefer `x = y + (z || 0)` the most.